# Group by area then by custom age range in R

Tags: r

I have two columns, one entitled 'Area' and one entitled 'Age'. I am looking to present these in a graph grouped by area and then by custom age band. Below code changes the ages in to the correct values that are required but can anyone advise necessary code to then create an object that groups by Area then by age, i.e. similar to below table example?

```
MyData["Age"] = cut(MyData$Age, c(0, 17, 24, 44, 64, 84, Inf), c("0-17", "18-24", "25-44", "45-64", "65-84", "85+" ), include.lowest=TRUE)
```

| Area | 0-17 | 18-24 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Area1 | 3 | 5 |
| Area2 | 5 | 7 |

Comment: Try `table(MyData)`.

Comment: Thanks, that works in terms of putting together the table I would like, but in the console - can you advise please how to convert this in to an object that I can view using View?

Comment: `result <- table(MyData)` then you can `View(result)`.